# Netty KeepAlive working too well for load balancer

Tags: netty, keep-alive

We have a system handling REST requests with an embedded Netty server. The system is on three machines behind a load balancer.

We connect to the system and send requests pretty much continuously.

The problem is that the connections are kept alive forever, so if one machine goes down and comes back up, it never gets any requests.

Apache has a config option MaxKeepAliveRequests which is the maximum number of requests in one connection before it will close the connection and open another.

Is there an equivalent in Netty? Or do I need to do this myself?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this yourself. Basically you would just do this in a SimpleChannelInboundHandler or ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter and close the connection once you process x requests.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like things have changed since first answer was given. *maxKeepAliveRequests* can be configured as described here:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServerConfig.html

> *int maxKeepAliveRequests()*
>
> The configured maximum number of HTTP/1.1 requests which can be served until the connection is closed by the server.